# What file permissions and owner to set for Pharo/Seaside deployment on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, deployment, permissions, pharo, seaside

What owner and permissions do i set, when i deploy a Pharo/Seaside application on Ubuntu for the **VM**, the **image** and for the **directory** containing those files?
I also use Object Serialization as described in the Seaside Book as persistence strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends how your setup looks like.

I like to create a user (named for example 'seaside') dedicated to running a Seaside application. I install the VM and image in the seaside home directory and run it as seaside. So all the ownership is for the 'seaside' user.

Comment: Ok, thank you, i deployed my application with this solution. I'm new to Linux and am interested to see what are common/good practices..